# /vendor/autoload.php error while running laravel

Tags: laravel, vendor

I just downloaded composer, created new project through terminal in vscode, tried to run it and this error shows up

[Error in localhost>public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqmXP.png)

The Code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and also getting errors while compiling on these:

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
$request = Request::capture()   //Undefined type 'Illuminate\Http\Request'//
)->send();
```

the illuminate code:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... how did you create the new project? also it would be better if you could copy that error and put it into your question as text

Comment: Did you try running a composer update command?

Comment: Warning: require(B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public\index.php on line 35

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='B:\xxampbruh\php\PEAR') in B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public\index.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public\index.php on line 35

Comment: yep, still no luck

Comment: Re-installed everything in the same (C) directory and its working great now Appreciate the help, thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You should have following code for autoload.php. Basically, you're trying to look for vendor directory in the public folder, whereas it is normally placed in the base directory

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Warning: require(B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public\index.php on line 35

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='B:\xxampbruh\php\PEAR') in B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public\index.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in B:\xxampbruh\htdocs\lsapp\public\index.php on line 35

Comment: by the way i just figured it out that my vendor location is in my C drive but the program is looking for it in the B drive, how do i change that?

Comment: Could you figure that out?